# VT100 terminal emulation for a Java-based 8-bit computer emulator

Tags: serial-port, gnu-screen, terminal-emulator, vt100, retro-computing

I am successfully using GNU Screen as serial terminal to "talk" to my Altair 8800 clone (http://altairclone.com/) using serial line. The command I use is 'screen -istrip /dev/ttyUSB0'. Screen does the VT100 emulation, strips off MSB from output etc. - works perfect.

Now, I am also working on an emulator of Altair 8800 in Java and would like to use some terminal emulator to connect and talk to it, just like it was a real machine behind serial device. What is the best way to solve in in the Linux world? Is there a way to use Screen for that? Something tells me the solution is trivial, but I just don't know it yet ;) Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You emulator has to create a something called a "pseudoterminal". This is a pair of devices - the master side is used by the terminal emulator, writing bytes that are to be sent to the program on the computer and reading bytes that the computer sends. The slave side is on the other end: it is the device that the program being controlled by the pseudoterminal opens to get input and send output to. The slave device will appear in the filesystem with a name like "/dev/pts/9". See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dTerminals.html.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to get the vt100 emulation in Linux make sure the terminfo package is installed and  set TERM=vt100; export $TERM after opening your terminal window